# Correct implementation of the Median of two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, median, sorting

I just tested myself on implementing median of two sorted arrays like described here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_H50Ir-Tves.
Is this implementation correct? Thank you in advance. Katarina

PS: the algorithm compute() returns 7 for the passed arrays. if I merge both arrays and detect the median by calling median() method directly the value 7 is returned again. So I assume that this algorithm behaves correctly but maybe there are some border cases and circumstances when it doesn't work. Can you give me feedback whether this implementation is correct?

public class Median {

```
public static class MedianDetector {

    public MedianDetector() {}

    public int median( int[] arr) {
        if( arr.length == 1 ) return 0;
        int rest = arr.length%2;
        return arr.length/2+rest;       
    }

    public int compute( int[] a, int[] b ) {
        int aMed = median(a);
        int bMed = (a.length+b.length)/2-aMed; //median finding formula

        if( a.length == 1)
            return a[0];
        if( b.length == 1) 
            return b[0];

        if( b[bMed] <= a[aMed] && a[aMed] <= b[bMed+1] ) {
            return a[aMed];
        } else
        if( a[aMed] <= b[bMed] && b[bMed] <= b[bMed+1] ) {
            int[] _a = new int[ a.length - aMed -1 ]; 
            System.arraycopy(a, aMed+1, _a, 0, _a.length);  
            int[] _b = new int[ bMed];
            System.arraycopy(b, 0, _b, 0, _b.length);   
            return compute( _a, _b);
        } else
        if( b[bMed] <= b[bMed+1] && b[bMed+1] <= a[aMed]) {
            int[] _a = new int[ aMed];
            System.arraycopy(a, 0, _a, 0, _a.length);
            int[] _b = new int[b.length - bMed-1];
            System.arraycopy(b, bMed+1, _b, 0, _b.length);
            return compute( _a, _b);                
        } else{
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[] {1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9};
    int[] b = new int[] {5,6,7,8,8,8,9};                                
    System.out.println( (new MedianDetector()).compute(a,b) );  //returns 7

    int[] total = new int[a.length+b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a,0,total,0,a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b,0,total,a.length,b.length);
    //total list: [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]

    List<Integer> totalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for( int t : total )
        totalList.add(t);
    Collections.sort(totalList);
    System.out.println(totalList);      
    System.out.println( (new MedianDetector()).median(total) );
    System.out.println( totalList.get( (new MedianDetector()).median(total) ) ); //returns 7 as well
}
```

}

Comment: this is not really nice, to ask other to see if it works right... you should doit, and if you have problems which you can't resolve with what you find with google's help, then you can come back and ask us to help you with that certain problem

Comment: Do you have an example of some input that does not product the output you expect?

Comment: The `7` is coming from this line: `if( b.length == 1) return b[0];`.  You are dividing your arrays down to one element and as soon as `a` or `b` reach one you are retuning it's contents.  I think you are supposed to be calculating the median of the `b` array before you reduce it's size

Comment: But I'm hesitant to offer this as an answer because this code is hard for me to follow

Comment: @Jason you are right;  this is a rubish: if( a.length == 1) return a[0]; ... . Maybe the first array isn't big enough but the second array still contains lots of elements. IMHO, if this scenario occurs both arrays should be merged, sorted and the final median value might be detected. Am I right?